# Dealloc not called on subview with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I have a not usual architecture. With one UIViewController and many subview's. I use UIView like viewController and UIViewController for transition animation.

UIView with many subview, which i push on main window, i removeFromSuperview and all ok, but subview not call dealloc method. Also i try to clean objects

```
- (void) dealloc {
    NSLog(@"ActivityShowVC dealloc");
    [showView removeFromSuperview];
    showView = nil;
}
```

This called.

```
- (void) dealloc {
    NSLog(@"ActivityShowView dealloc");

    [mainScroll removeFromSuperview];

    [titleView setDelegate:nil];
    [titleView removeFromSuperview];
    titleView = nil;

    [photoView setDelegate:nil];
    [photoView removeFromSuperview];
    photoView = nil;

    [predictionView setDelegate:nil];
    [predictionView removeFromSuperview];
    predictionView = nil;

    [calendarView setDelegate:nil];
    [calendarView removeFromSuperview];
    calendarView = nil;

    [descriptionView setDelegate:nil];
    [descriptionView removeFromSuperview];
    descriptionView = nil;
}
```

But this have some problem.

Comment: Where did you define dealloc?

Comment: As far as I know you don't have to worry abour remove subviews from superview in dealloc method. All superview will be removed and deallocated when your superview will be deallocated. Just leave delegate = nil in your dealloc method. ARC should take care about the rest.

Comment: i solved it. Problem was in delegate, which keep my views!

Answer (score 5):

If `dealloc` is implemented and not called then there is something retaining the instance. You need to rethink the strong references to it.

Dealloc is not a good place to do anything other than releasing resources since the instance is no longer fully functional nor in a complete state. Doing things like: `[showView removeFromSuperview];` are best done explicitly prior to deallocation.

As @Greg stated, most or all of what you are doing in `dealloc` is not needed under ARC. Subviews are now generally `weak` so no explicit dealloc is necessary. In fact they may be already gone depending on the order of the teardown of the view hierarchy.

Comment: I successfully used `dealloc` to break retain cycles in `UIViewController`s, but I stumbled upon a retain cycle which I solved by replacing `dealloc` with `removeFromSuperview`. Though the method's name sounds like is the best place to dealloc your stuff, why do you say that it's a bad place? And what other place is good for `UIViewController`s?

Comment: What does that have to do with my question? I didn't say that I'm calling `dealloc`, just that I overwrite it in `UIViewController`s and it's working ok. `UIViewController`s don't have the `removeFromSuperview` method for example.

Comment: True but it was unclear to me in the comment what "replacing dealloc with removeFromSuperview" means.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved a similar problem.  In my Viewcontroller, I have a NSTimer pointer created, when I put the code below in 'viewWillDisappear', 'dealloc' is called.

```
if (_timer) {
        [_timer invalidate];
        _timer = nil;
    }
```